# Ожидание объекта в памяти

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь дождаться объекта из разделяемой памяти. Вообще, это возможно?
Есть две программы: одна посылает данные в память, другая читает:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR nameForMutex[] = TEXT("Local\\some_name");

TCHAR szMsg[16];
int sz = 3;

int _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    HANDLE hMutex;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;

    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
        NULL,                    // default security
        PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
        0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
        BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
        szName);                 // name of mapping object

    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, true, nameForMutex);

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);

        return 1;
    }

    _stprintf_s(szMsg, _T("%d"), sz);

    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    int ch = _getch();
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

    /*int help = _ttoi(pBuf);

    cout << help << endl;*/

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Клиент:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR nameForMutex[] = TEXT("Local\\some_name");

int _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    HANDLE hMutex;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;

    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, nameForMutex);
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
        FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
        szName);               // name of mapping object

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);

        return 1;
    }

    int help = _ttoi(pBuf);

    cout << help << endl;

    /*TCHAR szMsg[16];
    int sz = 5;

    _stprintf_s(szMsg, _T("%d"), sz);

    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    _getch();*/

    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении данного кода, если запустить клиент, но не ввести значение на сервере, чтобы скопировать его в память, клиент не видит, естественно, ничего в памяти и завершается. Хотелось бы, чтобы клиент не завершался, а ждал, пока сервер не отправит в память данные, а клиент сразу же считает их из памяти и выведет. Пытался сделать с помощью `WaitForSingleObject(hMapFile, INFINITE);`, но программа пропускает эту строчку и идет дальше. Возможно ли вообще как-нибудь дождаться?

Comment: Я же Вам ещё в прошлом ответе написал: Вы не можете ждать на куске памяти. Либо постоянно читайте из неё и проверяйте, есть ли там что-то, либо заводите синхронизирующий элемент, на котором ждать - семафор, condition variable и т.д.

Comment: ixSci, в том вопросе я не очень понял про синхронизацию, т.к. тогда еще она была не нужна. А как через семафоры это реализовать? Ведь его как-то нужно передать клиенту?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WaitForSingleObject пробует захватить объект синхронизации. Если ему удается, поток продолжает выполняться, если нет, то поток ожидает момента, когда функция сможет захватить объект. Разделяемая память не является объектом синхронизации, поэтому использовать ее так, как у вас в программе, нельзя. В вашем случае можно использовать Event или Mutex, еще есть вариант с отправкой [сообщения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) клиенту о том, что информация записана в память и ее можно считать.

Пример с мьютексом: 
Сервер:

```
HANDLE hMutex;    

int main() {
    //что-то там ваше
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, true, "Local\\some_name");
    //некоторый код, который записывает в память данные
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    //что-то еще
    return 0;
}
```

Клиент:

```
HANDLE hMutex;    

int main() {
    //что-то там ваше
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, "Local\\some_name");
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    //некоторый код, который читает данные из памяти
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    //что-то еще
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Здесь есть все что нужно по эвентам и другим объектам синхронизации: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Спасибо. Я, кстати, пытался с помощью Event сделать, но не получилось. В "сервере" после строки `CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));` я добавил `SetEvent(hMapFile);`, но этого, я думаю, не достаточно.

Comment: @compl Вы не совсем поняли. Каждый объект в WinAPI имеет хендл, по которому на него и ссылаются. hMapFile (у вас) – это хендл файла, в котором у вас разделяемая память расположена. Для того, чтобы сделать свой эвент, надо создать новый хендл, обозвать его, например, 'hEvent'. В сервере: создать его функцией 'CreateEvent', установить его через 'SetEvent', потом закрыть, когда он больше не нужен. В клиенте: создать его, и ждать с помощью 'WaitForSingleObject'. Пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @compl Добавил простой пример в ответ.

Comment: Теперь понятно! Спасибо!

Comment: И еще, в моем случае Event или Mutex не важно? Т.е. не важно что использовать?

Comment: Не важно. Они отличаются, но вам подойдет любой из них.

Comment: у меня снова проблемы :)
Вставил Mutex как в вашем коде. Но при запуске клиента сразу вылетает месседж `Could not open file mapping object`, т.е. клиент опять не ждет сервера. Если сначала включить сервер, а потом клиент, все хорошо. Код обновил в вопросе. Может порядок не тот где-то?

Comment: @compl, это нормальная ситуация. Клиент не должен ждать сервер, если он не запущен. Он должен завершаться ошибкой.

Comment: @ixSci, точно. Но всё же, возможно ли как-то дождаться сервера, даже если он не запущен?

Comment: @compl, можно сделать бесконечный цикл, который будет проверять запущен ли сервер. Проверку "запущен ли сервер" можно реализовать через что угодно, можно проверять наличие процесса, можно проверять не записал ли он какие-то данные, не создал ли именованный мьютекс и т.п.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо. А как будет выглядеть проверка "не создал ли именованный мьютекс"?

Comment: @compl, используйте `OpenMutex()` для открытия мьютекса и проверяйте возвращаемое значение. Подробнее про функцию можете почитать в [справке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684315(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN